# Which index is used ? ORACLE DB SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select *
from sometable 
where column1='somevalue' and column2='someothervalue'
```

For the above query if both column1 and column2 have index tables ix1 and ix2, then which index is used for the above example? assume that 'somevalue' and 'someothervalue' are existing values in the table and column1 and column2 have non unique values.

Also how would it differ if the and was replaced by or?

Comment: Look up Explain Plan which is usually available in GUI tools like SQL developer and Toad

Comment: It depends on the statistics of the table and indexes, on whether you have histrograms or not, on the value of your literals, etc., etc.. They can even be used both with index merge. However, If you'll use OR, I believe you'll get a table access full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index that is used is the one that the oracle optimizer believes is best for the query.  "Best" in this case means the most selective -- that is, which single condition matches the fewest rows (estimated based on the statistics on the table).

For your query, the best index is either `sometable(column1, column2)` or `somtable(column2, column1)`.  With equality conditions, either matches the `where` clause.

With an `or` the situation is much tricker.  I think that Oracle can use both indexes for the query (check the explain plan), but this is more likely with a `union`/`union all`:

```
select *
from sometable
where column1 = 'somevalue' or
selet *
from sometable
where column2 = 'someothervalue' and column1 > 'somevalue';
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite impossible to say, depending on many elements; for example:

```
create table someTable ( column1 number, column2 number);
create index someIndex1 on someTable(column1);
create index someIndex2 on someTable(column2);
insert into sometable values ( 1,10);
insert into sometable values ( 2,10);
insert into sometable values ( 3,10);
insert into sometable values ( 4,20);
insert into sometable values ( 5,30);
insert into sometable values ( 5,40);
insert into sometable values ( 5,50);
commit;
```

Now I see the following:

```
    SQL> select * from sometable where column1 = 1 and column2 = 10;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1247292719

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |            |     1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SOMETABLE  |     1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SOMEINDEX1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLUMN2"=10)
   2 - access("COLUMN1"=1)
```

**Same behaviour** with different filter:

```
SQL> select * from sometable where column1 = 5 and column2 = 40;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1247292719

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |            |     1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SOMETABLE  |     1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SOMEINDEX1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLUMN2"=40)
   2 - access("COLUMN1"=5)
```

Now I **calculate statistics** and try again:

```
    SQL> select * from sometable where column1 = 5 and column2 = 40;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2029385636

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |            |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SOMETABLE  |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SOMEINDEX2 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLUMN1"=5)
   2 - access("COLUMN2"=40)
```

Now it has stats on my table, so it decides to use the **second index**, which performs better for the filters I gave.
Now I try to change again the filters:

```
SQL> select * from sometable where column1 = 2 and column2 = 10;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1247292719

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |            |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SOMETABLE  |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SOMEINDEX1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("COLUMN2"=10)
   2 - access("COLUMN1"=2)
```

... and it uses again the **first index**, which is the best to match my conditions.

Even in this simple sequence, you can see how different can run a query, depending on data, statistics, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably (in common case) for the first query it will be intersection of record sets (1)x(2) where (1) column1='somevalue' and (2) column2='someothervalue'.

For the last it will be union (1)+(2).

Both recordsets can be produced by "its" index.

Some additional words

```
CREATE TABLE test as select * from user_objects;
CREATE index ndxOt on test(object_type);
CREATE index ndxC on test(created);
SELECT * FROM TEST where OBJECT_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW' or CREATED = TO_DATE('12.12.2014 16:40:57', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

and the plan for 'OR'

```
SELECT STATEMENT Step 6 of 6     ALL_ROWS    6 18  38548 419
  CONCATENATION Step 5 of 6          5 0 0 0   
    TEST_USER.TEST TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED) Step 2 of 6 TEST_USER  TEST  ANALYZED  BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED  2 2 736 8   
      TEST_USER.NDXC INDEX (RANGE SCAN) Step 1 of 6  TEST_USER  NDXC  ANALYZED  RANGE SCAN  1 1 0 8
    TEST_USER.TEST TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED) Step 4 of 6 TEST_USER  TEST  ANALYZED  BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED  4 16  37812 411
      TEST_USER.NDXOT INDEX (RANGE SCAN) Step 3 of 6 TEST_USER  NDXOT ANALYZED  RANGE SCAN  3 1 0 411
```

Comment: I did not understand  your reply...please elaborate.

Comment: Condition "column1='somevalue'" make some set of records where value of field "column1" equals 'somevalue'.
Condition "column2='someothervalue'" make different set of records where value of field "column2" equals 'someothervalue'.
Each set can be received using the corresponding index.
The result of the query with AND will be an intersection of these sets.
The result of the 'OR' will be an union of these sets.
Ok?